# Can I represent time-complexity as a summation (complexity of elements of different length)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Let's say I have to iterate over every character in an array of strings, in which every string has a different length, so `arr[0].length != arr[1].length` and so on, as this for example:

```
#prints every char in all the array
for str in arr:
    for c in str:
        print(c)
```

How should the time complexity of an algorithm of this nature be represented? A summation of every length of the element in the array? or just like `O(N*M)`, taking N as number of elements and M as max length of array, which it overbounds accordingly?

Comment: For the sake of convenience, we almost always use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a precise mathematical theory called complexity theory which answers your question and many more. In complexity theory, we have what is called a Turing machine which is a type of computer. The time complexity of a Turing machine doing a computation is then defined as the function f defined on natural numbers such that f(n) is the worst case running time of the machine on inputs of length n. In your case it just needs to copy its input into somewhere else, which is clearly has O(n) time complexity (n here is the combined length of your array). Since NM is greater than n, it means that your Turing machine doing the algorithm you described will not run longer than some constant times NM but it may halt sooner due to irregularities of the lengths of elements of the array.

If you are interested in learning about complexity theory, I recommend the book *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser, which explains these concepts from scratch.

Comment: While you’re right that Turing machines can be used to rigorously define what time complexity means, it’s extremely rare to see TMs popping up when analyzing actual programs because they’re fairly unwieldy to work with.

Comment: @templatetypedef Turing machines constitute an important part in learning the complexity theory. OP asking about an elementary question indicates that their understanding of the concept is limited and that they should learn the theoretical aspect of it for a deeper understanding. However, I disagree with you about they being unwieldy, because you do not need to describe them in full detail in order to inspect their complexity. After you get used to them, it becomes very easy to describe them in "high level" and make sure that you can build it if you have asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. Your bound of O(NM) is a conservative upper bound. You could also define a parameter L indicating the total length of all the strings and say that the runtime is Θ(N + L), which is essentially your sum idea made a bit cleaner by assigning a name to the summation. That’s a more precise bound that more clearly indicates where the work is being done.